# pandas: slice dataframe based on NaN

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have following dataframe `df`

```
prod_id prod_ref
10      ef3920
12      bovjhd
NaN     lkbljb
NaN     jknnkn
30      kbknkn
```

I am trying the following:

```
df[df['prod_id'] != np.nan]
```

but I get exactly the same dataframe.

I would like to display

```
prod_id prod_ref
10      ef3920
12      bovjhd
30      kbknkn
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use function [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) or inverting [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
print (df[df.prod_id.notna()])
   prod_id prod_ref
0     10.0   ef3920
1     12.0   bovjhd
4     30.0   kbknkn

print (df[~df.prod_id.isna()])

   prod_id prod_ref
0     10.0   ef3920
1     12.0   bovjhd
4     30.0   kbknkn
```

Another solution is [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), but need specify column for check `NaN`:

```
print (df.dropna(subset=['prod_id']))
   prod_id prod_ref
0     10.0   ef3920
1     12.0   bovjhd
4     30.0   kbknkn
```

If in another columns are not `NaN` values, use [Alberto Garcia-Raboso's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601897/2901002).

Comment: @gabra - thank you for edit, unfortunately I edit answer too, so community rejected it

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `np.nan != np.nan` is `True` (alternatively, `np.nan == np.nan` is `False`). Pandas provides the `.dropna()` method to do what you want:

```
df.dropna()
```

Output:

```
   prod_id prod_ref
0     10.0   ef3920
1     12.0   bovjhd
4     30.0   kbknkn
```

By default, `.dropna()` will drop any row that has a `NaN` in any column. You can tweak this behavior in two ways:

- check only some columns using the `subset` argument, and
- require that the row contains `NaN` in *all* columns (in the `subset`, if you are using it) using `how='all'` — the default is `how='any'`.

You can check the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Comment: Thank you, especially for the explanation `np.nan != np.nan` and `np.nan == np.nan`.